# Fluent D record_transformer plugin and Ruby for eventual use with elasticsearch,Kibana

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I am currently using the fluentd record_transformer plugin to transform syslog messages. I wanted to know how to implement this set of c++ commands in ruby to find a comma and get a substring up to that position and store it in a new field (Duration):

```
std::string str="We think in generalities, but we live in details.";
std::size_t pos = str.find(',');
std::string newstring = str.substr (3,pos);
```

I have tried :

```
<filter xyz.**>
@type record_transformer
enable_ruby true
<record>
Duration ${record["message"][32..(("message".index(/\,/,32)).to_i)]}
</record>
```

But have been unsuccessful. I acknowledge this is a rather basic question, but all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<source>
  @type dummy
  dummy {"message": "We think in generalities, but we live in details."}
  tag dummy
  @label @INPUT
</source>

<label @INPUT>
  <filter>
    @type record_transformer
    enable_ruby true
    <record>
      duration ${record["message"].slice(/,([^,]{3})/, 1)}
    </record>
  </filter>
  <match>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</label>
```

This will print like followings:

```
2018-09-12 19:29:08.029546388 +0900 dummy: {"message":"We think in generalities, but we live in details.","duration":" bu"}
2018-09-12 19:29:09.031650493 +0900 dummy: {"message":"We think in generalities, but we live in details.","duration":" bu"}
2018-09-12 19:29:10.033424279 +0900 dummy: {"message":"We think in generalities, but we live in details.","duration":" bu"}
```

If you want to parse syslog format lines, you can use https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parser_syslog instead of filter_record_transformer.

Comment: thanks for your answer I will give your suggestion a shot and update